# convert string from ETHER to THREE using python

Tags: python-2.7

python code to convert following inputs

input  -> output

ETHER -> THREE

OZONETOWER -> ZERO ONE TWO

Comment: tried anything yet? if yes, please post it here. Also, although it is roughly clear what you want to do with the input, it would be better & clearer if you specify the same in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if X=='ETHER':
    X='THREE'
```

something like that.